# Add column in middle of the table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

we have a existing table in SQL Server DB.
we need to add a column to the existing table.
here is the existing columns,

```
col1, col2, col5, col6
```

here is the columns which has to be added to the table,

```
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6 - in this sequence we need to add in SQL Server.
```

can you please help me out in this

Comment: AFAIK, SQL Server can only add new columns at the end.

Comment: The order of the columns within the table shouldn't matter anyway. You can control the order of the column in the `SELECT` if you need to; there is no reason to `DROP` and re`CREATE` a table just because you want a column to be in a different ordinal position,

Comment: @jarlh Actually, if i understand the question correctly, in SQL Server Management you can create a new column, via the design view, and drag the column up to the position you want

Comment: @JamesS, yes it can. But I don't know how it handles different types of dependencies, like foreign keys, since it - as I understand it - drops columns and then adds them after the new column.

Comment: @James Using the SSMS gui, you have the option of saving any change you make to a script. If you do that, you can see the SQL that SSMS generates to accomplish that. To add a column "in the middle", the GUI will generate a script that completely recreates the table which is the only way to accomplish this.